# Is it "שמן המור", or is it "אנפקינון"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, tractate-megillah, oil, olive-oil

In [Megilah 13a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13a.18?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B6%D7%9E%D6%B6%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%9E%D6%BC%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A8&with=Lexicon&lang2=he) we bring down a פסוק which talks about what the woman did before going to אחשוורוש to try + become king:

"For six months, they anointed themselves with "שמן המור"

We then ask - what is "שמן המור?"

Reb Chiya Bar Abba says - it's a type of oil called סטכת.

Reb Huna says - it's oil from olives that only reached one-third of its growth.

We then bring down a *Braysa* which quotes *Rabbi Yehuda*:

"אנפקינון is oil from an olive which has only reached one-third of its growth."

*STIRA!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!111*

Is it "שמן המור", or is it "אנפקינון"?

Comment: Might it be saying to Rav Huna "no, what you are thinking of is called ______, not the stuff we are discussing."?

Comment: Maybe it has two names?

Comment: @Mike could be, but the Lashon of the Gemara says seems to say otherwise